# OpenSSL with Java

Tags: java, openssl

I have to use OpenSSL in a Java web project and I don't know anything about 'OpenSSL'.

How can I integrate OpenSSL with my project? is there any good fundamental tutorials to learn this?

Comment: OpenSSL is a C library, and an awkward one to use at that. What's wrong with the [`javax.crypto`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/) or [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)?

Comment: Are these freely available???I don't have any idea that's y i'm asking form you,Thanxx again,

Comment: [Bouncycastle is MIT X11-derived license](http://www.bouncycastle.org/licence.html) (very free). No idea on the `javax.crypto` package, I got distracted when trying to muddle through the Oracle web site.

Comment: This is a legit question - Bouncycastle is not approved for certain security certifications such as FIPS 140-2.

Answer (score 24):

First of all: what do you need the library for?

- If you are going to use simple cryptographic functions, then use the [Java SE Security components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html) deployed with the JDK.
- If you need more advanced functions (such as some digital signing formats, etc), use a cryptographic library ([BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) is one of the the most popular)
- But, if what you need is to open SSL connections from Java code, and handle certificates authentication, etc, you won't need any of these:

  - If you are working on a Java EE Container, your container can validate incoming SSL requests: it's just a matter of configuration
  - Also, if you need to connect to a SSL port, the JDK presents some basic classes for doing so (see [this example](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=32388)). Note that in this case, you'll need to set some system properties on your java command.

Like these properties:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore_path
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore_path
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustword
```

Comment: What if you actually want to use OpenSSL though, for none of the above reasons.... is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 8):

**Apache Tomcat Native Library** is the solution.
https://github.com/apache/tomcat-native

It uses OpenSSL for TLS/SSL capabilities. You can use it as standalone library (as I did) or connect your Tomcat. It is open source project with well documented Java code.

Why tomcat native?

JSSE is slow and hard to use.
In my project to get best performance we've decided to find/write JNI wrapper for OpenSSL as possibility for upgrading certificates on-the-fly is a question mark and Key Stores are too complex.

As Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs is written in Java you cannot expect best efficiency.

Tomcat Native is a wrapper so you are limited only to capabilities of your OpenSSL version.

Comment: I'd like to use OpenSSL to build a PKI in my java project , would it be advisable to build a PKI using tomcat native ?

Answer (score 6):

Everyone talks about BouncyCastle, but in our use case Gnu Crypto library won the day. Native java.

Our database ( aerospike ) spends at least 10% of its time computing hashes in java, for some customers, simply because these implementations are slow. I welcome when there's a native implementation of the crypto libraries available on every Linux machine. I thought some of the Java7 VMs were going to include more algorithms, but I haven't seen them yet.

Answer (score 5):

Best solution: Use Java's built-in security for simple tasks or use BouncyCastle for more advanced ones.

If you HAVE TO use OpenSSL from Java you have 2 choices:

1. Call openssl as a process from Java.
2. Make a JNI layer to OpenSSL, but that seems like a complete waste of time to me.
   None of those are really good ways of doing it.

Comment: Another thing to consider if you need to use it with an HSM and it only supports OpenSSL Engine. But nowadays most HSM comes with JAR files for adapting to JCE/JCA

Answer (score 4):

You need to answer a few important questions before any suggestions

1) Do you really want to call C(native) implementation form JAVA?

2) What are the features in OpenSSL which cannot be solved by JCE and BouncyCastle

3) Is the scope just limited to using certificates generated by OpenSSL, decrypting files generated by OpenSSL?

Comment: Thankxx your support this helps me a lot

Comment: just FYI: OpenSSL isn't C++, it's plain C.

Comment: Answer to Q2: BC does not support HELLO for DTLS (so you will lose the first message in any communcation

Comment: 1) yes 2) interoperability and consistency across languages and platforms 3) nope

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of Java native libraries for crypto.   However they are generally not *fully* interoperable with OpenSSL, are sometimes significantly slower (see the metrics on the site below), and aren't supported on all platforms.  OpenSSL is definitely supported on nearly every platform and is, generally, performant.

That being said, there are some security advantages to using VM-based crypto.  This should also be a consideration.

The Apache group has built a library for Java that uses JNI to access openssl for AES encryption.  I think it's the best public example of using JNI to access openssl, and you can reference it easily using maven.

https://github.com/apache/commons-crypto

If you want, you can pull out the JNI binding portion of the libary and implement the functions you need.

This makefile shows how to use javah to get what you need from the .class to build the .c code:

https://github.com/apache/commons-crypto/blob/master/Makefile

Specifically, this line in the Makefile calls javah:  `$(JAVAH) -force -classpath $(TARGET)/classes -o $@ org.apache.commons.crypto.cipher.OpenSslNative` to produce the correct "OpenSslNative.h" file based on the OpenSslNative.class.

https://github.com/apache/commons-crypto/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/crypto/cipher/OpenSslNative.java

Note how `import java.nio.ByteBuffer;` is used to allow for C output buffers.

The associated .c program is here:

https://github.com/apache/commons-crypto/blob/master/src/main/native/org/apache/commons/crypto/cipher/OpenSslNative.c

It's written with cross-platform support in mind, and is a good example.   Every exported function must begin with `JNIEXPORT`, and you can see how the full class path is in each function name.

I've seen a lot of bad JNI bindings, passing strings around, etc.  Starting with a solid base goes a long way toward building good OpenSSL integration in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keytool java tool in your `java\jdk\jre\bin` directory.