# Calling OpenSSL from Java code

Tags: java, openssl

I wanted to know if there is any way to call OpenSSL library functions (not the command-line tools) from Java code. Specifically I want to use OpenSSL to securely read from and write to a socket created by Java code. If JNI is the solution then is there any pre-written JNI that I can use? I am also aware of JSSE and JCE but I'd still like more information regarding this query.

Comment: Yes, you can by using JNI or JNA; however you're asking if anyone has already written one which is a software recommendation. Some googling indicates that it's unlikely that there's anything that encompasses all of openssl.

Comment: [you dont need OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5416890/351861)

Comment: Also see [Android Native Development Kit Cookbook](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1849691509) from Packet Publishing. I believe there are two chapters on calling into a native DLL from Java using OpenGL as an example. I also seem to recall Packet Publishing puts the chapters online for download.

Comment: Thanks for the insight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSL with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416194/openssl-with-java)